# What's the difference between repulsive Delta function and Attractive Delta Function?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, potential, schroedinger-equation, terminology, dirac-delta-distributions

What's the difference between repulsive Delta function and Attractive Delta Function? I need to clear the concept. Please note that I know what's the Delta function.

Comment: can you clarify where you saw the term "attractive delta function"? could it be that it is in a description of a potential between two particles and then the meaning is that the coefficient multiplying the delta function is negative?

Answer (score 2):

The difference is simply whether the factor multiplying the delta function is positive or negative. A potential that is a positive delta function is an infinitely high and infinitely thin potential *hill*. One that is a negative delta function is an infinitely high and infinitely thin potential *well*.